# What is the period of $f(x) = \sin^4(x)+ \cos^4(x)$?

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry, periodic-functions

This is an elementary problem but I'm just not getting the right answer.

My reasoning is as follows:
The period of $g(x) = \sin^4(x)$ is $\pi$ and that of $h(x) = \cos^4(x)$ is $π$ as well, so the period of the function $f(x) = \sin^4(x) + \cos^4(x)$ should be the LCM, which would be $\pi$. Plotting the function, however, shows that the period is $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Why is that? What am I missing here? I'm sorry if this is trivial, but I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: Hint: $1=(\sin(x)^2+\cos(x)^2)^2=\sin(x)^4+\cos(x)^4+\sin(2x)^2/2=\sin(x)^4+\cos(x)^4+(1-\cos(4x))/4$

Comment: Generally speaking, the sum of two functions of period $a$ is not necessarily of period $a$. Just take $f-f=0$, for instance. Or less trivially, the difference of two trigonometric polynomials $f,g$ which have the same first few terms.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni That is a "moster" of a "Hint."  But +1 for the comment.

Comment: Thanks @Dr.MV (for the "moster" as well :-))

Comment: @RaymondManzoni My pleasure. ;-))

Comment: Find the intersection points of sin and cos and you get the answer to your question.

Answer (score 12):

After [some nice trig manipulations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1525976/what-is-the-period-of-fx-sin4x-cos4x/1525979?noredirect=1#comment3107474_1525976), you can find that

$$\sin^4(x)+\cos^4(x) = \frac{\cos(4x)+3}{4}$$

which has a period of $$\frac{2\pi}{4} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Solid answer!  +1

Comment: It's "solid" for those of us who already know how to do it.

Comment: Nice edit :) +1

Answer (score 3):

$$\sin^4x+\cos^4x=(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)^2-2\sin^2x\cos^2x=1-\frac12\sin^22x$$
as a result has a period of:
$$\frac{2\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ and $g$ have period $\pi$, then $f + g$ has period of *at most* $\pi$. For example, $f = \sin$ and $g = -f$.

Comment: Thank you! So f(x) can have a period of at most the LCM of the periods of g(x) and h(x) here?

Comment: @UtkarshPant: well, not sure LCM is defined well for non-integers, but if you say that $z = \mathrm{LCM}(x,y)$ is smallest positive number such that $z/x, z/y\in \Bbb Z$ then yes. That just follows from the definition of periodicity.

Comment: I don't see how your example is related to your first sentence. A constant function has *any* nonzero number as a period, thus it's certainly not *at most $\pi$*.